# What the biggest size of output that std::codecvt::unshift() can need?

Tags: c++, locale, iostream, streambuf, codecvt

I am working on a custom file `streambuf`. Now, I want to flush on seek like `fstream` does. At this point I want to know how big the array for output of [`std::codecvt::unshift()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt/unshift) should be? It seems to me that the size returned by [`std::codecvt::max_length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt/max_length) should be enough. Is my assumption right?

Comment: From the article you cite: "No more than `to_end-to` characters are written." Is this not sufficient?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: It is sufficient not to overwrite memory beyond my supplied buffer. But I want to know the size in advance so that I can avoid having to loop if my provided buffer is not big enough.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you think there is some sort of required size for `unshift`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Because there seems to be a problem if the buffer is not big enough to store whole multi-byte sequence. See my other question related to this which describes problems with the `out()` function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357027/trouble-with-stdcodecvt-utf8-facet